# Inserting data into database using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to insert data into my database by using ajax but for some reason my code is not doing that. Here is what I have so far:

Index page:

```
<form id="notify" action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="note-wrapper">
        <div class="note-title">New Employee</div>
        <input type="hidden" name="employee_id" value="<?php echo $employee_id; ?>" id="employee_id">
        <p>Name</p>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        <p>Description</p>
        <textarea name="text" id="text"></textarea>
        <div class="action-wrapper">
            <button class="cancel-btn">Cancel</button><button class="submit-btn flt-rt" type="submit" name="new_note">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>  
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#notify').submit(function() {
    var employee_id = $('#employee_id').val();
    var name = $('#name').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {employee_id:employee_id, name:name},
        url: 'notify',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });

});

</script>
```

When the script is run I get my error page which is usually displayed when it cannot find a page that is requested but I have the notify page created and I can access it through the browser when I manually point to it.

Notify page:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', "Off");

$employee_id = $_POST['employee_id'];
$note_name = $_POST['name'];

if(!empty($employee_id)) {
    $objBreeze = new Breeze();

    $objBreeze->createEmployee($employee_id, $note_name);

}
```

Breeze class:

```
<?php

class Breeze extends Application {

    private $table_2 = 'employee';

    public $path = 'media/';

    // Notes CRUD
    public function createEmployee(array $params) {
        if(!empty($params)) {
            $params['date'] = Helper::setDate();
            $this->db->prepareInsert($params);
            $output = $this->db->insert($this->table_2);
            $this->id = $this->db->id;
            return $output;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getEmployee() {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM {$this->table_2} ORDER BY `date` DESC";
        return $this->db->fetchAll($query);

    }
```

The above database CRUD works perfectly fine on my other projects. If anyone has a clue as to what I am doing wrong I would be grateful for your help friends.

Comment: `createEmployee(array $params)` expects an Array as the parameter. When you call it `$objBreeze->createEmployee($employee_id, $note_name);` You are not passing an array !!!! You are passing 2 scalar parameters

Comment: * I can access it through the browser when I manually point to it.* Share the url you used manually, where it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `notify` script is calling `Breeze::createEmployee` incorrectly. The method expects an array as a parameter and you are passing 2 scalar variables

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', "Off");

$employee_id = $_POST['employee_id'];
$note_name = $_POST['name'];

if(!empty($employee_id)) {
    $objBreeze = new Breeze();

    //$objBreeze->createEmployee($employee_id, $note_name);
    //                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    // my guess would be you need somthing like this
    // I have to guess as you dont show what 
    // $this->db->prepareInsert($params); does 
    $params = array('employee_id' => $_POST['employee_id'], 
                    'name' => $_POST['name']);
    $objBreeze->createEmployee($params);
}
```

Comment: Thanks friend, you were right about the scalar variables.

Answer (score 0):

The URL is wrong. You are posting to:

```
url: 'notify',
```

Replace it with the actual URL.

Comment: I have tried adding 'notify.php' but it makes no difference.

Comment: If OP is using a routing mechanism this may be the correct url

Comment: what is the relative url of the Ajax page with reference to the page that is calling this ajax?